# Wix bootstrapper uninstalling MSI package in silent mode

Tags: wix, bootstrapper

I have an msi bundled with prerequisites using Wix bootstrapper (burn.exe).
We migrated this project from Installshield to WiX.
The installation works fine.
However, during repair or uninstall the bootstrapper runs the msi-file in silent mode.
Since the last dialog (e.g. 'SetupCompleteSuccess') within the msi file contains some controls to trigger some more actions.
Is there a possibility to configure the bootstrapper so that the msi file is executed in 'UI'-mode?

Answer (score 1):

In WiX v3, it is not possible. Burn explicitly shows internal UI only during initial install. WiX v4 changes how that works: https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/5616